# Text elements (text2, text2heading, text4, and text4heading) not showing in Compose layout

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I'm unable to display text2, text2heading, text4, and text4heading in my Compose layout. I've checked for missing string resources, modifier conflicts, and text color issues, but the problem persists. What elsecould be causing this behavior?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun composableCard(text: String, textheading: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier, backgroundColor: Color) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
            .background(backgroundColor),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = textheading,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = text,
   textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
        )
    }
}
```